# Centos - top takes 100% cpu

Tags: linux, centos, cpu, top

I have a CentOS server where I'm running the `top` command, I can see that the process `top` utilize 100% CPU.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`top` command will read `/var/run/utmp` file to get active user number. if the file is too large to read. top spends more time to read it that may occupy 100% CPU usage. reduce utmp size, the top command won't occupy much CPU usage

Comment: It also depends on what time interval the command uses to refresh its status display. Setting it to `0` will easily make it use 100% of CPU.

Comment: @Kusalananda YES. you are right.